# After creating threads using CreatThread api the output on the console consists of question marks

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

everyone... I've just started to learn how to create process and thread using Windows API. My code does work if I want thread to display integer on the screen but it doesn't work when using array of chars... Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<strsafe.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N 4
#define bufferSize 255

DWORD WINAPI Threader(LPVOID Parameter);

typedef struct Data {
    char value[bufferSize];
} Data, *pToData;

int main()
{
    int i;
    char c[bufferSize];
    pToData threadData[N];
    HANDLE handleArray[N];
    DWORD threadID[N];

    FILE *file=fopen("niti.txt", "r");

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s", c);
        threadData[i] = (pToData) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(Data));
        strcpy(threadData[i]->value, c);
        handleArray[i]=CreateThread(NULL, 0, Threader, threadData[i], 0, &threadID[i]);
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(N, handleArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(handleArray[i]);
        if(threadData[i] != NULL)
        {
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, threadData[i]);
            threadData[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Threader(LPVOID Parameter)
{
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    TCHAR messageBuffer[bufferSize];
    size_t cchStringSize;
    DWORD dwChars;
    pToData dataArray;
    char temp[bufferSize];

    hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if( hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return 1;

    dataArray=(pToData)Parameter;

    StringCchPrintf(messageBuffer, bufferSize, TEXT("Parameter = %s\n"), dataArray->value); 
    StringCchLength(messageBuffer, bufferSize, &cchStringSize);
    WriteConsole(hStdOut, messageBuffer, (DWORD)cchStringSize, &dwChars, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

If I change **value** in my struct to **int** and do the same in **main** the output is correct. Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably compiling for Unicode but outputting  a char array. Your symptoms sound like an encoding mismatch and Unicode output function mis-matched against ANSI char array is the mismatch that results in lots of questions marks.

In other words I hypothesise that your code resolves `StringCchPrintf` as `StringCchPrintfW`. And you then fail to satisfy the contract by passing `char*` rather than `wchar_t*` when you pass `dataArray->value`.

Use `wchar_t` or `TCHAR` instead of `char` for `dataArray->value`. Or call the **A** version of the output functions. Or compile for ANSI.

Comment: Thank you... __wchar_t__ worked like a charm! Also had to change __strcpy()__ to __wcscpy()__ Again, thank you very much!

Comment: You could use `_tcscpy` to match `TCHAR`, but I think you need to get on top of your text encoding before you go much further. It's a bit of a mish-mash right not I'm afraid.

Comment: I really should get on top of the text encoding... This thing was bothering me since yesterday! Do you have any links to pages worth of looking into them, regarding the subject (encoding, and usage in C/C++). Best regards!

Comment: I think you just need to decide on a single encoding and use it exclusively. Nowadays you should be using Unicode and on Windows the natural choice is the native Windows encoding, UTF-16. So use `wchar_t`, `wcscpy` and so on. Make sure that your app targets Unicode (yours does).